# Modify column before inserting XML value to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm trying to import a XML file into a MySQL Table. In the XML file there is a timestamp in <CurrentTime> in the following format:

> 2016-01-26T09:52:19.3420655+01:00

This timstamp should go into the corresponding DATETIME CurrentTime column in my Table. So I did the following

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'xxx.xml'
INTO TABLE test.events
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Event>'
SET CurrentTime = str_to_date(CurrentTime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f');
```

But it quits with the error

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2016-01-25T16:22:24.1840792+01:00' for column 'CurrentTime' at row 1

So it seems it doesn't convert the string at all. Why?

Comment: Interrestingly, declaring CurrentTime as a VARCHAR populates it with y proper DATETIME string....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that error is thrown when the string value from the file is loaded directly to the column.  The error is thrown *before* you get to the SET clause.

Here's an abbreviated example of how to use *user-defined variables* to pass the value of a field down to the `SET`, bypassing the assignment to the column.

Note that the columns `_row` and `account_number` are populated directly from the first two fields in the file. The later fields in the file are assigned to user-defined variables (identifiers beginning with `@`.

The `SET` clause evaluates the *user-defined variables*, and assigns the result of the expression to the actual column in the table.

In this example, the "dates" were formatted YYYYMMDD. I used the `STR_TO_DATE()` function to have that string converted to a proper `DATE`.

I abbreviated this sample somewhat, but it demonstrates the approach of reading field values into user-defined variables.

```
CREATE TABLE _import_water
(`_row`             INT
,`account_number`   VARCHAR(255)
,`total_due`        DECIMAL(18,2)
,`end_date`         DATE
,`start_date`       DATE
,`ccf`              DECIMAL(18,4)
)

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '//server/share$/users/me/mydir/myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE _import_water
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(_row
,account_number
,@total_due
,@end_date
,@start_date
,@ccf
)
SET `total_due`        = NULLIF(@total_due,'')
  , `end_date`         = STR_TO_DATE(@end_date,'%Y%m%d')
  , `start_date`       = STR_TO_DATE(@start_date,'%Y%m%d')
  , `ccf`              = NULLIF(@ccf,'')
```

---

Also, it doesn't look like there's any problem with your `STR_TO_DATE`, it seems to evaluate just fine.

testing...

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2016-01-25T16:22:24.1840792+01:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f') AS mydatetime
```

returns:

```
mydatetime
--------------------------
2016-01-25 16:22:24.184079
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use variables like in your examples, the CurrentTime column doesn't get populated at all.

Comment: Interrestingly, declaring CurrentTime as a VARCHAR populates it with y proper DATETIME string....

Comment: Furthermore, first converting the column to VARCHAR and then back to DATETIME works perfectly fine.

Comment: @leflic: Yes. Having the column defined as VARCHAR would avoid that error because the first assignment to the column doesn't require a conversion, then the SET can can perform an operation. User-defined variables work for me. (Without seeing the statement you're running, I can't explain why CurrentTime wouldn't get populated, I'd just be making guesses. When I do that, I do have to supply a complete list of columns/variables the fields get assigned to.)

Comment: @leflic: The error that was being thrown was because the value of the field is being assigned to the column. That assignment is done before the processing of the `SET`. The user-defined variable is just one approach to workaround that. (User-defined variables in the column list  can also be used to "skip" fields in the file we don't need.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally got it working. I didn't realize the variable must have the same name than the XML tag.

Comment: @leflic: My apologies. I missed that it was an XML file you were loading, (LOAD **XML** FILE).  The example I gave was for CSV file. With CSV, there's no restriction on what the variable names are, it's just by field position. I'm glad to hear you got it figured out.  You should consider adding a better answer to this question (especially regarding the naming of user-defined variables) when doing a LOAD XML FILE.